# Can't download data from _MobileSubscription table using FuelSDK and python

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, mobileconnect, python, datasource

I've set up FuelSdk on my airflow machine and I want to download some data from the _MobileSubscription table. but when I have a column starting with underscrore I'm getting this message

```
Failed to get <class 'FuelSDK.objects.ET_DataExtension_Row'> - Error: Invalid column name '_CustomObjectKey'.
```

and that's the code I'm running

```
client = self.get_conn()
getter = ET_DataExtension_Row()
getter.auth_stub = client
getter.CustomerKey = data_source
getter.props = ['_OptInDate', '_OptOutDate']
res = getter.get()
```

If I try on a different data source with columns that don't start with "_" it works fine.

Does anyone know what could be the issue?

Comment: _mobileaubscripition is a system object, I would recommend using the data view instead https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sms_subscription_log.htm&type=5

Comment: @EazyE I'm not even sure If I try to query the correct table, I'm mostly interested in getting data about mobile push notifications (opt in / opt out fields) Which in the data designer seems to be in "Mobile Push Demographics" and "Mobile Push Subscriptions" tables, but I can't find them anywhere. Do you happen to know where I can find them?